# Why return id from sharedInstance

Tags: objective-c, singleton

Many examples of the sharedInstance pattern return an id:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

instead of a class instance:

```
+ (MyClass*)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Why is this? Is one necessarily better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodaFi clearly articulates (+1) the basic `id` vs `instancetype` vs explicit return type issues.

But I think it's worth noting that the singletons's `sharedInstance` method adds a unique wrinkle to the discussion: The whole idea of `id` and/or `instancetype` is to make it easier to subclass. But that doesn't quite make sense within the context of a singleton's constructor method.

Let's say you have some code base in which you have some `sharedInstance` singleton method for some base class. And let's say that at some later point, you decide to subclass this class, but neglect to implement a new `sharedInstance` for the subclass. You'll therefore inherit the same base class implementation, with a single `sharedInstance` static. And if you used `instancetype`, the compiler will even lead you to believe that `[SubClass sharedInstance]` will return a shared instance of the subclass.

The problem is that you really do not have any assurance of which type of object you'll get if you call `sharedInstance` on the subclass. If you accidentally have some old code calling it on the base class, the object returned from the `[SubClass sharedInstance]` confusingly may be an instance of the base class! But if you're lucky enough to have remembered to remove any references to the base class `sharedInstance` method elsewhere in your project, you'll correctly receive an instance of the subclass. Clearly this is not a desirable situation, that the behavior of this inherited method may change depending upon how it was first called somewhere else in your code. This is antithetical to the very notion of a singleton.

Bottom line, while it's generally advisable to make classes extensible using inherited methods returning `instancetype` (or, in olden days, `id`), in the case of singleton's, I would not generally advise it with respect to the `sharedInstance` method. It mistakenly suggests an extensibility that doesn't quite apply in this case.

Instead I would suggest that (a) with `sharedInstance` method that you have it return the explicit data type; and (b) if you subclass the code, implement a new `sharedInstance` on the subclass. This eliminates the ambiguity.

Comment: Two excellent answers. I have accepted this one only because it addresses the singular issues of singletons, which was the genesis of my question, but my thanks and +1 to both, since the combination of the two will help not just myself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are major differences between returning `id`, `instancetype`, or specific classes from the standpoint of both design and maintainability.

`id`: Is the oldest of the bunch.  Unless it is used in methods from the `+alloc` or `-init` family, type inference is forgone and the returned object is assumed to have any type.  It is usually implicitly cast by the compiler to whatever concrete type you happen to use in your declaration.  `init`-family-style inference can be recovered with class methods by prefixing your method name with `alloc` or `new`, and in instance methods by prefixing the method name with `autorelease`, `init`, `retain`, or `self`.

`instancetype`: Is a newcomer that grants `-init`-family-style type inference to methods with "related" return types (as in related to the class they're confined to).  It relaxes the inference naming restriction `id` has by granting those semantics to any method marked with it as a return type.  Generally, it is preferred to `id` as you can recover more safety (or at least, get better warnings) about incorrect usages of certain methods not covered under the id restriction.

A class: should only be used when you are absolutely sure that the instance you vend will not have a specific subtype or wish to hide the fact that it does.  It is useful for class clusters like `UIColor` or concrete classes that should not have subtypes like `UIPasteboard`.  Thus it is typically used as a marker that inheriting from a particular class is unsafe.

tl;dr If you wish to discourage subclassing then be specific, else `instancetype`.